# remove br tags and leave all other tags

Tags: jquery, html

I just want to remove the br tags.

```
'<div class="temp">some content<br>and more<br><a href="#"> and more content</a></div>'

$('.temp br').contents().unwrap();
```

why doesn't this work.

I also tried this as I saw it on stackoverflow but didn't work either. What am I doing wrong with both of these.

```
$('.temp').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).filter('br').remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work because it's wrong. Try this:

```
$('.temp br').remove();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KE5kA/).

To replace them with spaces:

```
$('.temp br').replaceWith("&nbsp;");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KE5kA/1).

Comment: `unwrap` is for tags that contain things, `<br/>`s simply exist.  The filter thing looks like it could work, but has too much going on.

Comment: Also I would like to be able to remove the the br tags but replace them with a space so the words are not lokking like they are joined.

Comment: Not really, because I really dont understand either of your approaches, or what drew you to them. My understanding is "remove all line breaks within selector". Your two approaches just don't fit at all, so I thought a working solution would be better than trying to 'splain. :)

Comment: So your saying unwarp does not work on br tags but works on every other tag. Like <p> tags

Comment: Ah levi I get you now. only tags that are wrapped around content. So if I use the remove is there a way to add space instead of the br tags

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/p6Mzu/. There is also a CSS only solution that is commented out in the link, as this only removes them.  The jQuery replaces the `<br>` with `&nbsp;`.

jQuery:

```
$(".temp br").replaceWith("&nbsp;");
```

CSS:

```
.temp br { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.temp br').before('&nbsp;').remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/before/ 
http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: In this case, nothing productive. It literally means "put a space before the br, then remove the br". @Zhenya - while this *does work*, the `.before` call is totally unnecessary and wasteful.

Comment: @karim79 you're right. replaceWith slipped out of my mind. I was posting this before you edited your post (or during) so didn't see it.

Comment: @Chapsterj I'm new to participating here at stackoverflow... is a link with an explanation usually not enough? if you follow http://api.jquery.com/before/ it explains it right there in a sentence at the very top.